# How to group sequence based on group column assign a groupid

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, join, merge

Below is the dataframe I have

```
ColA  ColB  Time          ColC
A     B     01-01-2022    ABC
A     B     02-01-2022    ABC
A     B     07-01-2022    XYZ
A     B     11-01-2022    IJK
A     B     14-01-2022    ABC
```

Desired result:

```
ColA  ColB  Time          ColC   groupID
A     B     01-01-2022    ABC     1
A     B     02-01-2022    ABC     1
A     B     07-01-2022    XYZ     2
A     B     11-01-2022    IJK     3 
A     B     14-01-2022    ABC     4
```

UPDATED:
Below is the code executed after cumsum

```
df['ColC'] = df['ColC'].ne(df['ColC'].shift(1)).groupby([df['ColA'],
                                                                                                                        df['ColB']]).cumsum()


ColA  ColB  Time          ColC   groupID
A     B     01-01-2022    ABC     1
A     B     02-01-2022    ABC     1
A     B     07-01-2022    XYZ     2
A     B     11-01-2022    XYZ     3 
A     B     14-01-2022    XYZ     4
A     B     14-01-2022    XYZ     4
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not fully clear, but it looks like you're trying to group by week number (and ColC):

```
df['groupID'] = (df
 .groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], dayfirst=True).dt.isocalendar().week,
           'ColC'], sort=False)
 .ngroup().add(1)
)
```

output:

```
  ColA ColB        Time ColC  groupID
0    A    B  01-01-2022  ABC        1
1    A    B  02-01-2022  ABC        1
2    A    B  07-01-2022  XYZ        2
3    A    B  11-01-2022  IJK        3
4    A    B  14-01-2022  ABC        4
```

Comment: Hi @mozway Thank you for your response. I am not trying to group by week. I am trying to assign a group ID whenever there is a change in ColC from previous row. For example, indices 0,1,are assigned groupID 1 because ABC is repeating in that sequence. Sudden change in XYZ increment the groupID by 1. The another fresh occurance of ABC is a separate groupID (index 4)

Comment: OK, then a simple `df['groupID'] = df['ColC'].ne(df['ColC'].shift()).cumsum()` should work. Why the "based on date and time" in your title?

Comment: I wanted to groupby ColA and ColB in this as well. Sorry for misleading with question

Comment: `ne` stands for "not equal". Then `df['groupID'] = df['ColC'].ne(df['ColC'].shift()).groupby([df['ColA'], df['ColB']]).cumsum()`

Comment: actually this solution is not working.I will edit the post with the updated table upon execution

Comment: you should better improve your example to include another group(s) and clearly explain the logic ;)

Comment: My aim is to detect the change in value based on previous row and assign a groupID accordingly. If ColC is something like this A,A,A,A,B,B,A then my groupid will 1,1,1,1,2,2,3 ...value 2 came because A changes to B and value 3 is because B changes to A.

Comment: Well, this is really a variation of what I described above, but the specifics you want are too unclear to give you an exact code.

Comment: Apologies.It is working. I need to group by near shift as well.  df['groupID'] = df['ColC'].ne(df.groupby(['ColA[,'ColB'])[ColC'].shift()).groupby([df['ColA'], df['ColB']]).cumsum()